# Simple login function for XBMC (Python) issue

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, xbmc, kodi

I'm trying to scrape sections of a Javascript calendar page through python(xbmc/kodi).
So far I've been able to scrape static html variables but not the JavaScript generated sections.

The variables im trying to retrieve are `<strong class="item-title">**this**</strong> , <span class="item-daterange">**this**</span> and <div class="item-location">**this**</div>` , note that they are in separate sections of the html source , and rendered through JavaScript. All of them scraped variables should be appended into one String and displayed.

```
response = net.http_GET('my URL')
    link = response.content
    match=re.compile('<strong class="gcf-item-title">(.+?)</strong>').findall(link)
    for name in match:
        name = name
        print name
```

From the above with regex i can scrape just one of those variables and since i need a String list to be displayed of all the variables together , How can that be done?

I get that the page has to be pre rendered for the javascript variables to be scraped But since I'm using xbmc , I am not sure on how i can import additional python libraries such as dryscrape to get this done. Downloading Dryscrape gives me a setup.py , **init**.py file along with some others but how can i use all of them together?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your question about the steps to scrape the JavaScript, how to use Python on XBMC/Kodi, or how to install packages that come with a **setup.py** file?

Just based on your RegEx above, if your entries are always *like* `<strong class="item-title">**this**</strong>` you won't get a match since your **re** pattern is for  **elements with class="gcf-item-title**.

Are you using or able to use BeautifulSoup?  If you're not using it, but can, you should--it's life changing in terms of scraping websites.

Comment: yes , I'm using Beautifulsoup , and theres three div's that i need to be appended into one string and printed , those 3 are the div's (including the strong text) mentioned in the question , they are generated through javascript, Any idea on how i can achieve this? I can use Beautifulsoup , But not some others.

Comment: and how do you use packages that come with a setup.py file with xbmc? i've found no answers on how to do that yet.

Comment: Check out [this link](http://kodi.wiki/view/Python_libraries) to see if it helps.  It looks like Kodi/XBMC want you to use a `from lib import <PKG>` approach by putting your _init_.py file in a **lib** folder